# Pgfplots: extra minor tickmarks

Tags: pgfplots

I've done a reasonable search (I think) to see if this has come up before and been answered, but couldn't find what I want.  If this is a repeat question, that'd be embarrassing...

I am trying to generate extra minor tickmarks and grid lines to go with it using \begin{axis} but without success.  I am able to create the extra grid lines that I want using the \draw command; there should be a better way, more so because I am currently guessing the location of the extra grid lines that I need.  Here's what I have as of now.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit,shapes.geometric,shapes.misc,positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,pgfplots.groupplots,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   axis x line = bottom,
   axis y line = middle,
   scale only axis,
   grid=both,
   grid style={line width=.2pt, draw=gray!20},
   major grid style={line width=.4pt,draw=gray!50},
   minor tick num=4,
   width=12cm,
   height=3cm,
   xmin=-2.25,xmax=2.25,
   ymin=0, ymax=1.5,
   xtick={-2,...,2},
   ytick={0,1},
   yticklabels={{},$1$},
   ylabel = {$x(t)$},
   xlabel = {$t$},
   extra tick style={
        grid=minor,
   },
   xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=north},
   y tick label style={anchor=south east},
   y label style = {anchor=east},
   enlarge x limits=0.1,
   axis line style = {-{Latex[length=3mm]}},
   clip=false,
   ]

  \addplot[black, ultra thick] coordinates {(-2.25,0) (-2,0) (-1,1)  (0,0) (1,1) (1,0) (2,1) (2,0) (2.25,0)};
 
  % the extra grid lines; the cs:x,y values were obtained by trial and error
  % how can I get them accurately doing something like
  % extra minor y ticks = {a, b}, extra minor x ticks = {c, d},
  % the extra lines are shown as red only to draw attention to them
  % they will be gray in the actual final plot
  % also need the missing the minor tick marks

  \draw[red!20, very thin] (axis cs:-2.2,0) -- (axis cs:-2.2,1.5);
  \draw[red!20, very thin] (axis cs:2.2,0) -- (axis cs:2.2,1.5);
  \draw[red!20, very thin] (axis cs:-2.4,0) -- (axis cs:-2.4,1.5);
  \draw[red!20, very thin] (axis cs:2.4,0) -- (axis cs:2.4,1.5);
  \draw[red!20, very thin] (axis cs:-2.7,1.2) -- (axis cs:2.7,1.2);

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here's what the above produces:

[image: se]

Comment: Why do you need to guess them? The coordinates are exactly the one you defined in the `axis` options....

Comment: I am confused because the axis is using the range -2.25 to +2.25. OTOH, I had to use -2.7 and +2.7, which are not matching the earlier numbers. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: You use `enlarge x limits` :-)

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing. Thanks! After getting rid of it I am able to match the grid position with what I had used for the x limits earlier.

Comment: Without changing the limit settings, you could use `\draw[red!20, very thin] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, 1.2) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}, 1.2);`, for instance instead of the last `\draw`.  Simpler is to use `extra x ticks={-2.4, -2.2, 2.2, 2.4}, extra x tick label=\empty`, but then I believe the grid style in `extra tick style` has to be either `major` or `minor`—no third independent style, AFAICS.

Comment: I followed your `extra x ticks` suggestion. The needed ticks are there alright but the end grid lines are missing if I used the `minor` style. I didn't expect the missing lines. If I change the grid style to `major`, then all the grid lines are there, but I don't want this `major` style.

Comment: @CSR I've posted my solution. Using `extra tick style={major grid style={...}}` allows one to have a third style *with drawn lines*. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to remove `enlargelimits`; you can use:

```
extra x ticks={-2.4, -2.2, 2.2, 2.4},
extra y ticks={1.2},
extra x tick label=\empty,
extra y tick label=\empty,
extra tick style={major grid style={line width=.2pt, draw=red!20}},
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   axis x line = bottom,
   axis y line = middle,
   scale only axis,
   grid=both,
   grid style={line width=.2pt, draw=gray!20},
   major grid style={line width=.4pt,color=gray!50},
   minor tick num=4,
   width=12cm,
   height=3cm,
   xmin=-2.25,xmax=2.25,
   ymin=0, ymax=1.5,
   xtick={-2,...,2},
   extra x ticks={-2.4, -2.2, 2.2, 2.4},
   extra y ticks={1.2},
   extra x tick label=\empty,
   extra y tick label=\empty,
   extra tick style={major grid style={line width=.2pt, draw=red!20}},
   ytick={0,1},
   yticklabels={{},$1$},
   ylabel = {$x(t)$},
   xlabel = {$t$},
   xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=north},
   y tick label style={anchor=south east},
   y label style = {anchor=east},
   enlarge x limits=0.1,
   axis line style = {-{Latex[length=3mm]}},
   clip=false,
   ]

  \addplot[black, ultra thick] coordinates {(-2.25,0) (-2,0) (-1,1)  (0,0) (1,1) (1,0) (2,1) (2,0) (2.25,0)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Otherwise, the computed limits can be accessed via `/pgfplots/xmin`, `/pgfplots/xmax`, `/pgfplots/ymin`, `/pgfplots/ymax`. For instance, the last `\draw` statement in your code could be replaced with:

```
\draw[red!20, very thin]
  (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, 1.2) --
  (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}, 1.2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It indeed produces what I was looking for. Is it possible to insert something like `\draw[options] (x1, y1) grid (x2,y2);` after the `\addplot` line to achieve the grid pattern that I want (with the grid lines passing through the major and minor ticks having their respective attributes)? Just curious. This will be another neat and satisfying solution, if it possible, that is. [Whatever little TikZ I know is via browsing this forum. I stand in awe of the expertise that is available here.]

Comment: While it is possible to put such a call before `\end{axis}`, I don't know how to have good control over the `xstep` and `ystep` of the grid in this situation. `pgfplots` uses a bunch of coordinate transformations; the `grid` operation is plain Ti*k*Z and doesn't know about them. It may be easier to simply draw lines (possibly using loops) or customize the available `pgfplots` grid styles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit,shapes.geometric,shapes.misc,positioning,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,pgfplots.groupplots,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line = bottom,
        axis y line = middle,
        scale only axis,
        grid=both,
        grid style={line width=.2pt, draw=gray!20},
        major grid style={line width=.4pt,draw=gray!50},
        minor tick num=10,
        width=12cm,
        height=3cm,
        xmin=-2.25,xmax=2.25,
        ymin=0, ymax=1.5,
        xtick={-2,...,2},
        ytick={0,1},
        yticklabels={{},$1$},
        ylabel = {$x(t)$},
        xlabel = {$t$},
        extra tick style={
            minor, grid num=3
        },
        xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, anchor=north},
        y tick label style={anchor=south east},
        y label style = {anchor=east},
        enlarge x limits=0.1,
        axis line style = {-{Latex[length=3mm]}},
        clip=false,
        ]
        
        \addplot[black, ultra thick] coordinates {(-2.25,0) (-2,0) (-1,1)  (0,0) (1,1) (1,0) (2,1) (2,0) (2.25,0)};
        
        \draw[red!20, very thin] (axis cs:-2.2,0) -- (axis cs:-2.2,1.5);
        \draw[red!20, very thin] (axis cs:2.2,0) -- (axis cs:2.2,1.5);
        \draw[red!20, very thin] (axis cs:-2.4,0) -- (axis cs:-2.4,1.5);
        \draw[red!20, very thin] (axis cs:2.4,0) -- (axis cs:2.4,1.5);
        \draw[red!20, very thin] (axis cs:-2.7,1.2) -- (axis cs:2.7,1.2);
        
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: From your response I am beginning to think that I've not conveyed clearly what I want. Your code produces a plot that has more extra x and y minor ticks between (-2,0) and (2,1). What I want are extra grid lines outside this range, i.e., a grid in the range (-2.4,0) to (2.4,1.2). My apologies for not wording it clearly. Rmano's comment under my question has addressed why I was not able to match the numbers: enlarge x llimits was the culprit.